# How display the main page when user opens the app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I'm developing an android application using Java and firebase. It's a college notification app. when i open my app it displays login page after login it displays the main page. If i close the app and reopen it it displays the login page. I want it to display the main page. I need a code for this problem.

Comment: Please post your MainActivity which you described to open on application start

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple scenario. You just have to made a couple of basic changes in your app.

To achieve this behavior, you have to do the following things.

1. Change your launcher activity from Login activity to Home activity.
2. In you Home activity, you should check if the user is signed in from Firebase, like this,

   ```
   if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
       // User not signed in. So navigate back to sign in activity.
   }else{
       // user is signed in. Your main home page logic here
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I know my question contain grammar mistakes. If i successful login to my app it displays home page. When i close that app and reopen it displays login page . I want it to display the home page. I need a Java code for that. I hope that you understand my question. Thank you